# Sticky Header in xamarin forms listview

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin.forms provides the ListView control. I followed the implementation of @jamesmotemagno for grouped list view. The application works fine. But the only problem is with sticky group header which comes default in ios and windows but not in android. This is very irritating just because of android I need to implement the custom rendering which led to render on ios and windows, which is not required. Is there any way to solve this problem of sticky header in android without disturbing ios and windows. Please suggest any solution for android.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question does not conform with the community's guidelines, and will soon be closed by a moderator. You should edit it appropriately if you expect to get any answers. Good questions usually include: **A desired outcome or result**, **What you have tried so far to solve your problem** and more.

Comment: you can do a custom render only for android and not disturb the ios/uwp, i assume you are using xamarin forms right? with mobile project and the platform specific ones right? i don't know the solution for the sticky header, but i know the solution to make a custom render only for android

Comment: The only solution is to have a custom renderer. As you explicitly said you don't want it you may use some technology other than Xamarin.Forms if it works better for you (and if it doesn't exist you may build your own), but this question makes no sense and should be closed.